# Bounty points if not accepted

Tags: discussion, bounty

Who will get the points if not a single answer is accepted after the bounty period is over?

Comment: refer this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/bounty

Answer (score 5):

TL;DR: Nobody:

Long answer:
From the bottom of this page: https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/bounty
Notice the last line in the paragraph.

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount (or the full amount, if the answer is also accepted). If two or more eligible answers have the same score (their scores are tied), the oldest answer is chosen. **If there's no answer meeting those criteria, no bounty is awarded to anyone**.